# Select average distinct values per day in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Don't know why this has me so stumped but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have a table with half a million sessions and need to get the average number of distinct mac address by day, since the beginning of time.

I've tried this:

```
def self.average_users_per_day
  self.average("distinct mac", :group => Chronic.parse("starttime"))
end
```

(Using Chronic because starttime is a string with timezone.. Have tried with DATE("starttime))

Over a large set of data, I get what I thought was a correct figure. Until I ran some tests and found that it's not actually grouping the results.

```
it "finds the average sessions per day", :focus => true do
  10.times do
    FactoryGirl.create(:session, starttime: Time.now, mac: (1..6).map{"%0.2X"%rand(256)}.join(":") )
  end

  10.times do
    FactoryGirl.create(:session, starttime: Time.now - 1.days, mac: (1..6).map{"%0.2X"%rand(256)}.join(":") )
  end
  Session.average_users_per_day.to_i.should eq 10
end
```

The result is always 20 and not 10.

What's the query supposed to look like? Any help appreciated - having a mind block.

Comment: you expect mac to be same in first 10 as next 10 `sessions` ??

Comment: No, there should be 10 distinct macs. 10 average sessions, per day. Have I lost it?!

Comment: i wonder why you're not getting errors in your tests.  your implementation of average_users_per_day should return a hash so calling .to_i to it should raise an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to work on the grouping function as it's unclear what the exact storage format of startime is but this should work for you:

```
def self.average_users_per_day
  self.from("(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT mac) AS macs FROM #{self.quoted_table_name} GROUP BY DATE(startime)) AS counts").average("macs").to_f
end
```

Just tested on a similar schema using mysql and seems to work.

Comment: Blimey, that looks interesting. Thanks, I'll have a play later.

Comment: Looks like it should work but the tests are still showing an average count of 20, not 10. Not sure the logic is quite right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about this, but wonder if you need to to parse the date in the SQL rather than afterwards with Chronic, and also think that the arel average will return an ordered hash of values, hence this is my attempt which I think works, although uses SQLite specific substr function to extract the dates from the the time string

```
def self.average_users_per_day
  sessions_per_day = self.select('distinct mac').group('substr(starttime, 0,11)').size.values
  sessions_per_day.inject(:+).to_f / sessions_per_day.size
end
```

Also, this returns a float so have tweaked the spec to:

```
Session.average_users_per_day.should eq 10.0
```

Comment: OH. So it's not as simple as previously thought? I'll giv it a shot with mysql. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry that this is not working at all for you, the more elegant answer by @mikeonrails also works for me as well, but as he points out getting the grouping right by day on your time string is an issue. I would be interested to see your solution.

Comment: No need to appologise. Your answer's led me to think of another way to do this. Testing later when I get back to my desk.